# Will a triboelectrically charged object in vacuum stay charged forever?

Tags: electrostatics

So, according to this question's answers:
[How does an object regains its neutrality after being charged by rubbing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23572/how-does-an-object-regains-its-neutrality-after-being-charged-by-rubbing)

Charge from triboelectrically charged object is removed by ionized moist air and potentially dust particles too.

So i wondered, what if we charge object in pure vacuum? It will stay charged forever, right?

I guess, in real vacuum of Space it will loose its charge, eventually, because there is stuff like occasional charged particles flying by. It should take much longer time, than in moist air, though...

Comment: Probably would stay charged for a long time if you put the charged object out in intergalactic space. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25378/how-vacuous-is-intergalactic-space

Comment: Quantum tunneling would result in a slow leakage of charge.  Cooling the object to nearly absolute zero would make the leakage much slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All matter can be describe by a phase diagram which describes at what temperature it changes from solid to liquid to gas. A charged blob of water in space will evaporate very fast, see [this answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98666/water-in-vacuum-or-space-and-temperature-in-space).

A solid object will take much longer to evaporate,the departing surface  molecules taking the charge with them. [This link](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/266548.pdf) has a table 2, in page 74, where the calculation has been done for a lot of materials studied for use in spacecraft . Of course a separate calculation would be needed for charged surfaces, depending on whether the molecular forces are more attractive or repulsive due to the charge.